# jQuery select n-first elements

Tags: jquery

I have a `tr` element

```
$('tr')
```

I need to select several first children (`td` in this case).

How can I do this?
`:nth-child()` can select even or odd elements. `:eq()` can select only one.

So the only way is

```
$('tr td:eq(0), tr td:eq(1), ... tr td:eq(n-1)')
```

Is there any shortcut?

Comment: Why not use .children() http://api.jquery.com/children/ ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `.children()` in this case. Just bad example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr td:lt(8)')
```

Use the [less than](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector

Also, note the comment in the docs

> Because :lt() is a jQuery extension
>   and not part of the CSS specification,
>   queries using :lt() cannot take
>   advantage of the performance boost
>   provided by the native DOM
>   querySelectorAll() method. For better
>   performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0,
>   index) instead.